# Group by with limit

Tags: mysql, group-by

My question is regards the performance.

What exactly happening when you use `group by` and then `limit`?

I have a very big table, when I query with `limit` and without `group by` its immediate. When I use `group by` with `limit 1` it takes forever. Now, the `group by` is running on an index, without the `group by` I get many potential "groups", items that will match the `group by`, so I don't need to worry there is only 1 group. So what I don't understand is why won't MySQL stop after the first group has been found when I put `limit 1`?

The query (even tried with `force index`):

```
SELECT fileso.hostId
FROM indicators.fileso fileso force index (hostId)
WHERE 1 = 1 
GROUP BY  fileso.hostId
LIMIT 1;
```

Without `group by` it's immediate.

Table Creation (large table):

```
CREATE TABLE `fileso2` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `hostId` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'code',
    `sha256` BINARY(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'meir',
    `fileName` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'meir',
    `fullPath` VARCHAR(350) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'meir',
    `datein` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `lastSeen` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `lastRA` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '?',
    `riskLevel` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1' COMMENT '?',
    `policiesViolated` VARCHAR(1000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `NTFSOwner` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'meir',
    `NTFSOwnerId` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1' COMMENT 'onIdle -done',
    `p_runningUser` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'meir',
    `p_parentUser` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `p_commandLineParams` VARCHAR(1000) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'meir',
    `p_runningUserId` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1' COMMENT 'onIdle -done',
    `p_ParentPath` VARCHAR(350) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'meir',
    `ar_regPath` VARCHAR(350) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'meir',
    `ar_regKey` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'meir',
    `ar_regValue` VARCHAR(350) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'meir',
    `s_serviceName` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'meir',
    `d_driverName` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'meir',
    `hostName` CHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `extension` CHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `uniqueness` BINARY(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00000000000000000000000000000000',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `uniqueness` (`uniqueness`),
    INDEX `p_runningUserId` (`p_runningUserId`),
    INDEX `riskLevel` (`riskLevel`),
    INDEX `lastSeen` (`lastSeen`),
    INDEX `hostId` (`hostId`),
    INDEX `datein` (`datein`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=2384056;
```

Comment: Is there an `ORDER BY`, too?

Comment: Please post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE My_Table\G` and also the text of your query.

Comment: no order by, added all the info

Comment: Please, don't give us a dumbed down query, give us a query that you need/use and makes some sense. The one you show is just useless, you can replace it with `select host_id from indicators.fileso limit 1 ;`. No `GROUP BY` needed and the problem is gone.

Comment: And also add the version of MySQL you use.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  You did not give enough info to answer your question.

Long answer:  This may cover your situation, plus explain a lot of other things...

In MySQL, `GROUP BY` implies the same `ORDER BY`.  (This is a non-standard extension.)  (But this point may be irrelevant.)

`GROUP BY` can be performed in two ways.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for both and, if possible, `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`; those may show the difference.

Plan A:  Gather all the data; sort it; walk through the sorted list doing the "grouping" stuff, such as `SUM`, `COUNT`, `MAX`.  (Actually there is a leapfrogging optimization for `MAX`.)  This lengthy process is what happens without the `LIMIT`.  Note that it gives `ORDER BY` for 'free'.

Plan B:  Keep a hash in memory; scan through the table (without any sorting); the result is in the hash.  Then it needs sorting.  (`ORDER BY NULL` avoids this sort.)

Both A and B involve at least a full table scan, so they do not explain your "immediate" response unless the table is quite small.  Is it?

Neither of those necessarily took advantage of any index.  So...

Plan C:  `INDEX(x)` and `GROUP BY x`.  In this case, the optimizer *may* choose to use the index as a way to avoid the 'sort'.  Furthermore if you have `LIMIT 1`, it only needs to do one value of `x`.  (Note: If there is a 'sort' in the pipeline, `LIMIT` cannot be done until *after* the sort; by then most of work has been done, so the limit does not save much time.)

Plan D (already alluded to):  If you are only doing `MAX`/`MIN`, then only the last/first row need be looked at.  If you also have a relevant index, it can reach into the index for the last/first row in each clump, thereby skipping all the other rows.  In this case, even without a `LIMIT`, you may get a significant performance boost.

**Caveat**

When doing `SELECT x, y FROM t GROUP BY x`, the engine is under no obligation to pick any particular value of `y`.  Furthermore the Optimizer seems to treat this case as "not worth optimizing", and may not do you what you expect (nor what I say above).  More on [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: Added all the info, but after reading your answer, still my main question is: If you group by indexed column and limit N, does the engine groups by the first N items he finds right?

Comment: Since you are going outside the definition of `GROUP BY`, all bets are off.  (I added a Caveat.)

Comment: @RickJames Did they post something on a comment I missed? I see only `SELECT x FROM t GROUP BY x LIMIT 1;` in the question. No `y` (or any other columns).

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - Doh!  Your point it well taken.

Comment: @Rick James, you miss understand me. What I asked was whether the limit 1 will be hit immediately after grouping the first item or will the group by complete and only after that the limit will occur. cause thats the behavior I see in my initial query

Comment: Sorry, I have not succeeded in reproducing your situation closely enough to get a good handle on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question for sqlite. Yes, it did do the obvious optimization.

```python
import sqlite3
import random

conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
                    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                    other_id INTEGER
                )''')

for i in range(50000):
    other_id = random.randint(1, i+1)
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO my_table (other_id) VALUES (?)''', (other_id,))

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

This

```
SELECT MAX(id), other_id
FROM my_table
GROUP BY other_id 
LIMIT 1;
-- Run Time: real 0.012 user 0.011253 sys 0.000632
```

is much faster than

```
SELECT MAX(id), other_id
FROM my_table
GROUP BY other_id;
-- Run Time: real 0.091 user 0.052810 sys 0.037161
```

`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` doesn't help answer the question:

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT MAX(id), other_id
FROM my_table
GROUP BY other_id LIMIT 1;
QUERY PLAN
|--SCAN my_table
`--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
```

but I could have figured it out from the VM instructions from `EXPLAIN`.